# Why were numbers on these income statements recorded differently from year to year?

Tags: investing, accounting, income-statement, annual-report

Below are two different income statements for Canadian Oil Sands Ltd. I am wondering how can their net income and other line items be recorded so differently across two consecutive financial statements?

[image: 2010 Income Statement]

---

[image: 2011 Income Statement]

Comment: The difference for net income is equal to crown royalties. I am guessing that is part of what is going on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell: The company in question changed its reporting standards in 2011.  Furthermore, in order to maintain an "apples-to-apples" comparison between 2011 and 2010 results, the results for 2010 had to be restated according to the new reporting standards.

See page 23 of their [2011 Annual Report (PDF)](http://www.cdnoilsands.com/files/COS_AR11_FULL.pdf).  Quote:

> **Transition to International Financial Reporting Standards**
>
> Canadian GAAP has been revised to incorporate International Financial
>   Reporting Standards (“IFRS”) and publicly traded companies like the
>   Corporation are required to apply such standards for years beginning
>   on or after January 1, 2011. Note 26 to the attached audited
>   consolidated financial statements discloses the impact of the
>   transition to IFRS on the Corporation’s reported financial position,
>   income and cash flows, including the nature and effect of changes in
>   accounting policies from those used in the Corporation’s audited
>   consolidated financial statements for the year ended December 31, 2010
>   which were prepared in accordance with Canadian GAAP prior to the
>   transition to IFRS.
>
> Financial measures for the year ended December 31, 2010 reported in
>   this MD&A as comparative figures have been adjusted to reflect the
>   transition to IFRS, as have the financial measures for all 2010
>   quarters reported in the summary of quarterly results on page 34. The
>   accounting policies applied in these audited consolidated financial
>   statements are based on IFRS as issued, outstanding and effective on
>   February 23, 2012.
>
> *[... more details in annual report ...]*